# Proving $\partial \bar N\subset \partial N$

Tags: general-topology

I wanted to prove [$\partial \bar N\subset \partial N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207933/the-topological-boundary-of-the-closure-of-a-subset-is-contained-in-the-boundary) in a different way, by showing if $x \in \partial \overline{N}$ then $x \in \partial N$. This I wanted to show by showing that if $U$ is an nbhood of $x$ then it contains

(i) a point of $N$ and

(ii) a point of $N^c$.

Since $U$ is an nbhood of $x$ it contains a point of $\overline{N}$ and a point of $\overline{N}^c$. We have $N \subset \overline{N}$ hence $\overline{N}^c \subset N^c$ hence (ii) is clear. What I'm stuck with is (i). I tried the following: $U$ contains a point $y$ of $\overline{N} = \partial N \cup \mathrm{int}N$. If $y \in \mathrm{int}N$ then we're done. If $y$ in $\partial N$ then either $y \in N$ or $y\in N^c$. If $y \in N$ we're done.

But if $y \in N^c$ then... nothing. So it looks as if $U$ could be a subset of $N^c$. Is it really not possible to prove it like this or do I just not see how? Thanks for help.

Comment: Since $\bar{N}$ is closed it contains its boundary. Hence an element of $\partial\bar{N}$ is also an element of $\bar{N}$. Shouldn't this be sufficient for (i)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clarification: In this post whenever I say the word *neighborhood* I mean an *open neighborhood*. (Based on the comments, it seems that this caused some misunderstandings. And I have to admit that I did not think about this when posting.)

If $x\in\overline N$ if and only if every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ contains a point from $N$.

$\boxed{\Rightarrow}$ Suppose that there is a neighborhood $U$ such that $U\cap N=\emptyset$. Then $N\subseteq X\setminus U$ and $X\setminus U$ is closed, hence 
$\overline N\subseteq X\setminus U$. I.e., $\overline N\cap U=\emptyset$, contradicting the assumption that $x$ is in this intersection.

$\boxed{\Leftarrow}$ If $x\notin\overline N$ then $U:=X\setminus\overline N$ is a neighborhood of $x$ such that $U\cap N=\emptyset$.

---

From this you can easily see that if every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point from $\overline N$, then every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point from $N$.

(Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x$. If $U\cap\overline N\ne\emptyset$, then we have a point $y\in U\cap \overline N$. Since $U$ is a neighborhood of $y$ and $y\in\overline N$, we get that $U\cap N\ne\emptyset.$)

Comment: In your last sentence, $U$ is a nbhood of $x$. Not necessarily of $y$. Or do we by convention assume nbhoods to be open?

Comment: You are correct, I should have written *open neighborhood* everywhere.

Comment: I don't know. I'm having a tired day. I'll re-read your answer in a few hours.

Comment: Dear Martin, I think my previous comment is irrelevant. However, regarding the last line of your answer: why is $U$ a neighbourhood of $y$? We assume it to be a neighbourhood of $x$. We need to argue why there is an open set $O$ such that $y \in O \subset U \cap \overline{N}$.

Comment: @MattN Would you agree that it is ok, if we know that $U$ is an open neighborhood? In the whole post I should replace neighborhood by open neighborhood - it would make it more clear.

Comment: No. If $U$ is open then why is $U \cap \overline{N}$ open?

Comment: But I don't need to show that $U\cap\overline N$ is open. (It is not even true in general.) I only need to show that $U\cap N$ is non-empty.

Comment: We want to show that $U \cap N \neq \varnothing$. We want to do this by using your lemma above. We have $y \in U \cap \overline{N}$. Hence $y \in \overline{N}$. Now if we can show that $U \cap N$ is a nbhood of $y$ then we can apply your lemma and are done. But why is $U \cap N$ a nbhood of $y$?(I'm sorry for the typo in my previous comment.)

Comment: It suffices to use te fact that $U$ is an open neighborhood of $y$. Then (using the lemma) $y\in\overline N$ implies $U\cap N\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting there. And why is $U$ a neighbourhood of $y$? (oh dear...)

Comment: Well, it is an open set and it contains $y$. (This is why I have to work with open neighborhoods, so that this argument works.)

Comment: Ouch x_x Thank you for your patience.