# In a normed set the boundary of a subset is contained in the boundary of the closure of the set.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space and $N$ a convex subset of $X$ (also $N^\circ \neq \emptyset$). I am trying to show that $\partial \bar N = \partial N$.
I found the proof that $\partial \bar N \subset \partial N$ from [The topological boundary of the closure of a subset is contained in the boundary of the set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207933/the-topological-boundary-of-the-closure-of-a-subset-is-contained-in-the-boundary) (the last comment), but I can't figure out the proof for $\partial N \subset \partial \bar N$.

This is what I've figured out:
Let $x \in \partial N$. We want to show that if $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ then $U \cap \bar N \neq \emptyset$ and $U \cap (X \backslash \bar N) \neq \emptyset$. 
Since $x \in \partial N$ then $U \cap N \neq \emptyset$ and $U \cap (X \backslash N) \neq \emptyset$.
Since $N \subset \bar N$ and $x \in \partial N$ then $U \cap \bar N \neq \emptyset$. How do I show that $U \cap (X \backslash \bar N) \neq \emptyset$? 
I've also noticed that I haven't used the fact that $N$ is a convex set.

Answer (score 1):

You do need to use the fact that it's convex with nonempty interior.  For example, in $X = \mathbb R^2$ the complement of a line gives a counterexample: its boundary is the line, but the boundary of its closure is empty.

Hint: by the Hahn-Banach separation theorem, there is a hyperplane 
containing $x$ such that ...

EDIT: OK, here's a hint for a proof without the separation theorem.  Suppose $x \in \partial N$.  Show that $2x - N^\circ = \{2x-y: y \in N^\circ\}$ is open and disjoint from $N$, and  contains points arbitrarily close to $x$.

Comment: I found several solutions using the separation theorem, but I'd like a proof that doesn't involve said theorem or hyperplanes. Is there any way to solve this only using basic topology properties (boundary, closure properties, convex set definition, open set definition etc)?

Comment: Let $x \in \partial N$. Then for every $r > 0$ $B(x,r) \cap N \neq \emptyset$ and $B(x,r) \cap (X \backslash N) \neq \emptyset$.
Lets look at the set $A := \{ 2x - y : y \in N^\circ \}$. Let $z := 2x - y$. Since $y \in N^\circ$ then  $\exists \rho > 0 : B(y, \rho) \subset C$.
Both $B(x,r)$ and $B(y, \rho)$ are open. Now I don't know what direction to go in because I'm not sure how all these balls intersect (or if they even do).

Comment: If $z = 2 x - y$ and $B(y,\rho) \subset N$, then $B(z,\rho) \cap N = \emptyset$, since if $w \in B(z,\rho) \cap N$, $(w + B(y,\rho))/2$ would be a neighbourhood of $x$ contained in $N$.

Comment: So if there was a $w \in B(z, \rho) \cap N$ then we would get a contradiction with the fact that $x \in \partial N$ because $(w + B(y, \rho))/2$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ contained in $N$ (which means that $x \in N^\circ$)
I'm not sure how to show that $(w + B(y, \rho))/2$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ because I don't understand the notation $(w + B(y, \rho))/2$. $\Vert z-x \Vert = \Vert x - y \Vert \leq ?$
We can conclude that $A \cap C = \emptyset$. I don't know how to show that $A$ is open and I'm not sure how I would use those facts (& the convex set definition) to get $x \in \partial \bar N$

Comment: I've been trying my best to figure this out but I'm finding it quite difficult.
I'm pretty sure that I can use the fact that $N^\circ$ is open to show that $A$ is open but I can't figure out how to do that.
Does $(w + B(y, \rho))/2$  mean the ball $1/2 B(w+y, \rho)$?
So if $A$ is open and disjoint from $N$ then $A \subset X \backslash N$ (and $A \subset X \backslash \bar N$?). Does showing that every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$ give me that $x \in \partial \bar N$? If so, how could I show that to be true? Also I'm still now sure where I will have to use the fact that N is convex.

Comment: $(w + B(y,\rho))/2$ means $\{(w+z)/2: z \in B(y,\rho)\}$.   Convexity of $N$ impiies that if $w \in N$  and $B(y,\rho) \subseteq N$, $(w + B(y,\rho))/2 \subseteq N$.   Continuity of the vector operations implies that $(w + B(y,\rho))/2$ is open.

Comment: Does the continuity of the vector space operations also imply that A is open?

Comment: Also why is this a neighborhood of x: $\Vert 1/2 (w+z) \Vert \leq 1/2 \Vert w \Vert + 1/2 \Vert z \Vert = 1/2 \rho + 1/2 \rho = \rho$.

Comment: Ok, i figured out the previous question but I'm confused if I still need to show that A is open? Or can I just use that $(w + B(y,\rho))/2$ is open to get that $x \in \partial N$?